# Disable aurelia-bundler just on dev machine?

Tags: gulp, aurelia

I've been working on an Aurelia app without gulp and it has gone well. Now I want to use gulp b/c the page loads are terrible with 100+ separate files being requested. I install aurelia-bundler from the skeleton and can get it working using gulp. But there are two problems:
1. I have to gulp bundle after EVERY change to refresh the page
2. The error messages make no sense b/c everything is minified now.

I can deal with #1 b/c of gulp-watch (even though that still takes time), but I can't handle the minified files and not being able to debug my code.

So, is there and easy way to switch back to the non-bundled files for development on my machine and only use the bundled files when I deploy to Heroku server? It seems like aurelia-bundle now points to the dist folder by default.

Oh yeah, I tried modifying config.js to point to "src" instead of "dist" but it still looks for the aurelia-xxx.js file instead of the non-bundled files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest build files you can `gulp watch` in dev which should use the src files **without bundling** - of course, this is slower, but in conjunction with browser-sync you shouldn't have to do loads of refreshes.

Check your `paths.js` and other config files against the skeleton if `gulp watch` is also bundling.